Why is nvcc giving the error "identifier "__builtin_ia32_ldtilecfg" is undefined" when including the SDL2 Library?
Relatively new to programming and I've been trying to make a 3D Rendering pipeline from scratch in C++ without the abstraction that OpenGL or Vulkan provide and I wanted to try implementing CUDA for hardware acceleration. It works great on some simple vector addition programs that I tested it on, but including SDL2 causes it to throw this error:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/include/amxtileintrin.h(42): error: identifier "__builtin_ia32_ldtilecfg" is undefined
    __builtin_ia32_ldtilecfg (__config);
    ^

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/include/amxtileintrin.h(49): error: identifier "__builtin_ia32_sttilecfg" is undefined
    __builtin_ia32_sttilecfg (__config);
    ^

2 errors detected in the compilation of "cuda.cu".
make: *** [Makefile:2: cuda] Error 2

I tried troubleshooting and to my understanding some compilers don't support Intel AMX. I'm not sure if CUDA does or not, or if there's a workaround.
I won't bother posting the code because it's just the inclusion of SDL2 causing the error, but the command in my Makefile is
nvcc -o cuda cuda.cu `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2

The header file referenced in the error contains the following:
/* Copyright (C) 2020-2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

   This file is part of GCC.

   GCC is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
   any later version.

   GCC is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   GNU General Public License for more details.

   Under Section 7 of GPL version 3, you are granted additional
   permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version
   3.1, as published by the Free Software Foundation.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License and
   a copy of the GCC Runtime Library Exception along with this program;
   see the files COPYING3 and COPYING.RUNTIME respectively.  If not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

#if !defined _IMMINTRIN_H_INCLUDED
#error "Never use <amxtileintrin.h> directly; include <immintrin.h> instead."
#endif

#ifndef _AMXTILEINTRIN_H_INCLUDED
#define _AMXTILEINTRIN_H_INCLUDED

#if !defined(__AMX_TILE__)
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC target("amx-tile")
#define __DISABLE_AMX_TILE__
#endif /* __AMX_TILE__ */

#if defined(__x86_64__)
extern __inline void
__attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
_tile_loadconfig (const void *__config)
{
  __builtin_ia32_ldtilecfg (__config);
}

extern __inline void
__attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
_tile_storeconfig (void *__config)
{
  __builtin_ia32_sttilecfg (__config);
}

extern __inline void
__attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
_tile_release (void)
{
  __asm__ volatile ("tilerelease" ::);
}

#define _tile_loadd(dst,base,stride)        \
  _tile_loadd_internal (dst, base, stride)

#define _tile_loadd_internal(dst,base,stride)               \
  __asm__ volatile                          \
  ("{tileloadd\t(%0,%1,1), %%tmm"#dst"|tileloadd\t%%tmm"#dst", [%0+%1*1]}" \
   :: "r" ((const void*) (base)), "r" ((__PTRDIFF_TYPE__) (stride)))

#define _tile_stream_loadd(dst,base,stride)     \
  _tile_stream_loadd_internal (dst, base, stride)

#define _tile_stream_loadd_internal(dst,base,stride)            \
  __asm__ volatile                          \
  ("{tileloaddt1\t(%0,%1,1), %%tmm"#dst"|tileloaddt1\t%%tmm"#dst", [%0+%1*1]}" \
   :: "r" ((const void*) (base)), "r" ((__PTRDIFF_TYPE__) (stride)))

#define _tile_stored(dst,base,stride)       \
  _tile_stored_internal (dst, base, stride)

#define _tile_stored_internal(src,base,stride)              \
  __asm__ volatile                          \
  ("{tilestored\t%%tmm"#src", (%0,%1,1)|tilestored\t[%0+%1*1], %%tmm"#src"}" \
   :: "r" ((void*) (base)), "r" ((__PTRDIFF_TYPE__) (stride)) \
   : "memory")

#define _tile_zero(dst)             \
  _tile_zero_internal (dst)

#define _tile_zero_internal(dst)        \
  __asm__ volatile              \
  ("tilezero\t%%tmm"#dst ::)

#endif

#ifdef __DISABLE_AMX_TILE__
#undef __DISABLE_AMX_TILE__
#pragma GCC pop_options
#endif /* __DISABLE_AMX_TILE__ */

#endif /* _AMXTILEINTRIN_H_INCLUDED */

I am on Fedora 39 using CUDA Toolkit 12.4 and g++ 13.2.1

Tried updating and reinstalling the CUDA Toolkit, hoping that maybe something didn't install correctly or I was on an outdated version. No difference.

Checked g++ but it was fully updated as well.

Tried trouble shooting online but couldn't find any documentation to help with fixing this issue. As mentioned earlier, though, I did come across some indication that it may be an issue with Intel AMX support with nvcc.


*EDIT: To clarify, the code works fine without using nvcc since I haven't added any CUDA code yet. g++ compiles it fine.

The CUDA GPU compiler doesn’t touch any of that code, it’s just compiling using your host g++ compiler. I would guess that the gcc build you have has AMX disabled (are you really sure that you don’t have two gcc versions installed and nvcc is finding a different version from what you think you are using?)

Tried a complete reinstall of gcc; no luck. tmk I haven't done anything to gcc or g++ since I installed fedora, since they come preinstalled already to my recollection. I can't imagine how I'd have two different versions installed for that reason.

A quick look into the release notes shows this: "Nvcc failed to compile immintrin.h for gcc 13 host compiler with -O2 option due to missing __builtin_ia32_cmpccxadd[64] support. This has been fixed in CUDA 12.4 Update 1". Maybe there is actually an incompatibility. Does your system actually have AMX extensions? What's your CPU?

CPU is an Intel i7-11700. Intel's site says AMX is enabled on 4th gen Xeon-scalable processors so it might very well be an incompatibility. That being said, SDL2 works fine without using nvcc. I can compile the code with g++ perfectly fine since I haven't actually added any CUDA code yet.

So this is weird, but I found that the code compiles fine if it has the .cpp extension rather than .cu. remember that I dont have any CUDA code yet so I don't think switching to .cpp is a solution but it is some information to consider

It seems like  if you have CUDA 12.4 and not CUDA 12.4 update 1, you should switch to CUDA 12.4 update 1.

It seems that the change in amxtileintrin.h from using an asm statement   __asm__ volatile ("ldtilecfg\t%X0" :: "m" (*((const void **)__config))); to the __builtin... method __builtin_ia32_ldtilecfg (__config); took place at gcc 13.2.1.  gcc 13.2.0 still has the asm method which nvcc seems happy with.  So another alternative is probably to switch from gcc 13.2.1 to gcc 13.2.0, then you could still use CUDA 12.4.  I can successfully compile immintrin.h on CUDA 12.4.0 with gcc 13.2.0

Because I've been hit with incompatibilities between nvcc and third-party headers in the past, I personally always try to separate the actual cuda kernels from the rest of the code, put them in a few .cu files and have them use as few outside headers as possible, with the rest of the code being standard c/c++ files. You don't need to mark files as .cu just to use the runtime API, for example. I suggest you try the same and file a bug report with Nvidia.

Trying gcc 13.2.0 worked! I haven't worked with large code bases much yet so I haven't had much experience with coding between multiple source files, but that's something I should really get used to so I'll give that a shot soon too.

this may also be of interest
